# Multiple SAM Templates with Same Custom Domain, Different Path Mapping

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam

I'm trying to create multiple services with different repositories; `actors` and `movies`. Each of these repositories have their own `template.yaml`

Unfortunately if I use the same domain but different base path in both of these `template.yaml`, I have errors and 2nd service is not deployed;

in **actors** repository; `template.yaml`

```
Mapping:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::BasePathMapping
    Properties:
      BasePath: actors
      DomainName: api.example.com
      RestApiId: !Ref Api
      Stage: !Ref Env
  Api:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
     # ... other props
```

in **movies** repository; `template.yaml`

```
Mapping:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::BasePathMapping
    Properties:
      BasePath: movies
      DomainName: api.example.com
      RestApiId: !Ref Api
      Stage: !Ref Env
  Api:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
     # ... other props
```

It looks like this can't be done. Even if I move the domain configuration within `Api` [resource definition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-property-api-domainconfiguration.html) it says the domain is being used in another stack as the stack names are also different.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create two resources with identical domain names.  This would allow for very bad things.

Instead,

**Option one 1 : Single  `AWS::Serverless::Api`**

Create one `AWS::Serverless::Api` resource with a single domain name and multiple Events

**Option 2 : Multiple `AWS::Serverless::Api`**

- Create multiple `AWS::Serverless::Api` resources with unique domain names (use the default one at creation)
- create a single `AWS::CloudFront::Distribution` resource with multiple Origins that are your `AWS::Serverless::Api`'s and the domain name you would like it to use. This way it will "front" that domain to your many origins (api-gateways)

**Notes:**

You may run into some syntax issues should you decide to continue to use multiple template files,  I'd recommend using a [nested approach](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-template-nested-applications.html)

Answer (score 0):

@Revenant this seems to be possible now. Your way doing it sound very legic right now.

1. Having a separate API per service
2. Having a separate basepath per service

- api.example.com/actors
- api.example.com/moviews

Just make sure your service supports to be called via the root path /